# How to make y-axis scales same size for each facet in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

Here is an example of the scenario:

```
df<-data.frame(t=1:8, V=c(1:4,seq(40,46, 2)), C1=rep(c('A','B'), 4), C2=rep(c('C','D'), c(4,4)))
```

This produces the following data frame:

```
  t  V C1 C2
1 1  1  A  C
2 2  2  B  C
3 3  3  A  C
4 4  4  B  C
5 5 40  A  D
6 6 42  B  D
7 7 44  A  D
8 8 46  B  D
```

I want to plot V vs t and split facets by C1 and C2.  I want the max(V)-min(V) to be the same for each facet, but max(V) and min(V) would be different, depending on the data range for each row of plots.  Here is where I am so far:

```
ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=t, y=V)) + facet_grid(C2~C1)
```

[image: default version]

max(V)-min(V) are of the same size, plenty of y-axis is wasted and trends are obscured by the extra range in each panel.  The other option is:

```
ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=t, y=V)) + facet_grid(C2~C1, scales='free_y')
```

[image: free_y version]

in which case, max(V)-min(V) = {6 for the 1st row of plots, and 3 for the 2nd row of plots}.

There is also no way to specify limits for each row, like we are able to do in lattice by passing a list with ranges to each panel to the ylim parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `space="free_y"` to `facet_grid()` to ensure that space between values are the same for each row.

```
ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=t, y=V)) + 
        facet_grid(C2~C1, scales='free_y',space="free_y")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It seems to work for the example I provided, so this answers the original question.  But my real graph is more involved than the example. I use some extra elements, like ribbons, points and lines derived from other data frames. It didn't like your suggested solution at first. I just transposed the facets and (somehow) y-scales are now of the same size. And the graph makes even more sense! I wonder why it wouldn't do the same without transposing the facets. I will try to come up with a reproducible example.